# perl - some substitute with regex

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone explain to me the following, what does it means start with substitute:

```
$delta_Value[$j] =~ s/(^.{12}).*$/$1/;
```

I want to know if it means that a `.` is at the beginning of the line and what it says next.

Answer (score 1):

This code will keep the 12 first characters and discard the rest. Using regex is not the best way of doing this though...

`^` means the start of the string
`.` is a placeholder for *any character*.
`{12}` means *12 times*
`.*$` means *everything until the end of the string*
and finally `$1` means *take the content in the first pair of parentheses*
`/` are just separators in Perl syntax: first part is the pattern, second part is the replacement string.

---

Equivalent code:

```
$delta_Value[$j] = substr $delta_Value[$j], 0, 12
```

Comment: Or `substr($var, 12) = q() if length($var) > 12` :)

Answer (score 1):

- `^` start matching with beginning of the string
- `(..)` capture group (first is `$1`, second `$2`, etc.)
- `.{12}` match any char except newline exactly 12 times (and store into `$1`)
- `.*$` match any char except newline till end of string
- `/$1/` replacement part of `s///` where everything matched so far is replaced with `$1`

Same could be achieved by matching only first 12 chars, instead of whole string,

```
$delta_Value[$j] = $1 if $delta_Value[$j] =~ /(^.{12})/;
```

Answer (score 1):

It means for position `$j` of Array `delta_value` delete everything but the first 12 characters

Perldoc is your friend: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 1):

The substitution operator matches and captures the first `12` characters at the beginning of the string while removing everything after that position and replaces the string with what was matched in the capturing group.

**Explanation**:

```
(          # group and capture to \1:
  ^        #   the beginning of the string
  .{12}    #   any character except \n (12 times)
)          # end of \1
.*         # any character except \n (0 or more times)
$          # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```